# how to append php code in the shortcode in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using the shortcode in the loop inside template file
and also using the lightbox form plugin.

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=9&post_type=packages') ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) :the_post(); ?>
  <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>          
   ...
    ...
    <?php echo do_shortcode("[formlightbox text='Book Now' title=the_title][contact-form-7      id='383' title='Booking Form'][/formlightbox]"); ?>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Please note that in the shorcode there is title=the_title and it is not appened to the anchor tag.
But when I use title='hello'or something else it gets appended to the anchor tag. 
I want current post's title should get appened to the rendered anchor tag via shortcode.

please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break the string and use the string concatenation operator to combine the function into your string.

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode("[formlightbox text='Book Now' title='" . get_the_title() . "'][contact-form-7      id='383' title='Booking Form'][/formlightbox]"); ?>
```

**Update**
This should use the `get_the_title()` as opposed to `the_title()` which echos the title.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried as above but it is now displaying title on the page and not gets appended to the anchor tag...

Comment: Actually the issue is with the_title. When I give some other field of post. it works well... Thankyou so much

Comment: Running do_shortcode() is an option for this use case, but not in general. People will most likely want to prepend/append code to shortcodes that are included in plugins or themes. This solution is not relevant in the majority of cases.